# mysql_query will not execute

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display all of the data from a table that I have made in mySQL. So far I am trying to run the query on the database but I am not able to run the query. Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "blah", "211018556") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($con,"basketball") or die ("Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM General";
mysql_query($query) or die ("Bad");

?>
```

my code continues to return bad when I get to that line. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am running PHP version 5.6.25

Comment: So you make a `mysqli_*` connection and then expect `mysql_*` to work?

Comment: *`or die ("Bad");`* - Yep.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if only php allowed `or breaking("Bad")`

Comment: @Dagon Loved every series; is that where you got your inspiration from?

Comment: hussh @Fred-ii- the Armenians are still after me.

Comment: I guess it's *"Back to the Future"* for you @Dagon